# java BufferedImage looses quality

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, graphics2d

In the following code, two lines are being drawn on the left side of the JFrame using the paintComponent method of a JLabel. The program also runs a method, which creates a BufferedImage with both lines painted on to it. The BufferedImage is then painted on to the right side of the screen. The method, which creates the BufferedImage follows the same procedure as the paintComponent method, however it is pretty clear that the BufferedImage looses a substantial amount of quality compared to the paintComponent method.

```
package pack;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(250, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

    public Test() {

        convertToImage();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(700, 700);
        setVisible(true);
        setContentPane(new label());

    }

    public class label extends JLabel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawLine(100, 100, 250, 250);
            g2d.drawLine(150, 350, 150, 500);
            g2d.drawImage(img, 300, 0, 250, 500, null);
        }
    }

    public void convertToImage() {
        BufferedImage image = img;
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawLine(100, 100, 250, 250);
        g2d.drawLine(150, 350, 150, 500);
        img = image;
    }

    public static class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {new Test();}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with using `g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)` on both image and label so when you create the image it's antialiased, and then you draw it on label which is antialiased second time.

Comment: Sadly not, it just causes the left two lines to also look terrible.

Comment: But at least they look identical.

Comment: Well I just tried every combination of having and not having antialiasing on the paintComponent method and the other method and they still look different each time.

Comment: Ok... you can sort of get it to work if you additionally set the rendering key to quality and the stroke control to pure. It looks much better for sure, you dont see individual pixels anymore and the position doesnt shift slighty down however it still looks a bit blurry. And in the context, in which i am using it, which is basically writing a knockoff Microsoft Paint, you really notice how the quality suddenly shifts from what you have drawn to what is displayed afterwards.

Comment: *it is pretty clear that the BufferedImage looses a substantial amount of quality* - not to me. They look the same. I use JDK11 of Windows 10. Post an image of what you see. *BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR* - don't know what the difference is but I've always used  *BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB*. Custom painting is typically done on a JPanel or JComponent. JLabel is transparent by default. Don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok I have just added two screenshots, on which the problem should become apparent.

Comment: Guess my eyesight is not that good. I don't see a difference in the drawn lines. On the other hand the left/right images from your paint ripoff looks completely different. Not sure what the issue is there other than my original question about the BufferedImage type. If you want to paint to a BufferedImage, then just add the BufferedImage as an ImageIcon to your JLabel. There is no need to override the JLabel.

Comment: Well they certainly look different. The right lines and the left circle thing are blurry and therefore brighter. The image from the paint ripoff look different, because I just drew two shapes in my program, which looked roughly the same. Again, the left one is converted to an image, the right one is drawn by the graphics2D drawPolyline method. Changing the type of the BufferedImage to TYPE_INT_ARGB unfortunately makes the picture look slightly worse and how would you add the ImageIcon to a JLabel? Setting it as the JLabels Icon doesnt work and you can only add Components.

Comment: *how would you add the ImageIcon to a JLabel?* - the same way you set the text. Read the JLabel API for the appropriate constructor or methods. See [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more info and working examples. Note, when you paint to the BufferedImage you will need to invoke `repaint()` on the label to make sure the updated image is painted.